# Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, docker

I installed Docker on my Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and when I type in my console:

```
sudo docker pull busybox
```

I get the following error:

```
Pulling repository busybox
2014/04/16 09:37:07 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/busybox/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: no answer from server
```

Docker version:

```
$ sudo docker version

Client version: 0.10.0
Client API version: 1.10
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): dc9c28f
Server version: 0.10.0
Server API version: 1.10
Git commit (server): dc9c28f
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Last stable version: 0.10.0
```

I am behind a proxy server with no authentication, and this is my `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.1.1:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://192.168.1.1:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://192.168.1.1:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://192.168.1.1:3128/";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the Windows users and boot2docker, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309

Comment: One minor detail: apt does not support SOCKS proxies at all.  `Acquire::socks::proxy` means  set the proxy for all URLs starting with a `socks` scheme.  Since your `sources.list` does not have any `socks://` URLs, that line is entirely ignored.

Comment: What about ``docker-compose``?

Answer (score 963, accepted):

Here is a link to the official Docker documentation for proxy HTTP:
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

A quick outline:

First, create a systemd drop-in directory for the Docker service:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Now create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

If you have internal Docker registries that you need to contact without proxying you can specify them via the `NO_PROXY` environment variable:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

```
$ sudo systemctl show --property Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
```

Restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

---

Footnote regarding `HTTP_PROXY` vs. `HTTPS_PROXY`: for a long time, setting `HTTP_PROXY` alone has been good enough. But with version 20.10.8, Docker has moved on to Go 1.16, which changes the semantics of this variable:
https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#net/http

For `https://` URLs, the proxy is now determined by the `HTTPS_PROXY` variable, with no fallback on `HTTP_PROXY`.

Comment: This works for Debian Jessie running Docker 1.6.2.  Somehow editing `/etc/default/docker` does not work.  Maybe I should remove `export` like the one documented for Centos.

Comment: For older SysV edit /etc/sysconfig/docker as in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html  - Oracle Linux 6.7

Comment: NB: I assumed that 'daemon-reload' would suffice to apply changes to docker, but actually `sudo systemctl restart docker` is strictly required for it to work.

Comment: Works for redhat 7, thanks, you saved my day. I tried a lot of proxy settings  and only this one works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
It helped me understand why docker couldn't download images, while connectivity seemed OK (browser, wget, ...) :
the Docker service is run as `root` and I hadn't configured the proxy for `root`! (so obvious, why didn't I see that !)

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04 refer @n3o 's answer, Since `systemctl ` is not available for ubuntu 14.04, it uses `upstart` to bring up the services.

Comment: Also in case you want to add a socks proxy, you might want to add this instead: `ALL_PROXY=socks5://<host>:<port>`

Comment: Works fine for me Ubuntu 16.04.    
Thanks

Comment: Worked on OEL7 with 4.1.12 kernel (the one you need for docker). Great reply mate, will reuse the info for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Now it is returning "Proxy Authentication Required"... how to config username and passoword?

Comment: @pinei I guess it would look like:
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=name:password@http://proxy.example.com:80/

Comment: Works for me too under centos7 - docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d. Though, I like to use systemctl edit --full docker.service, since I want to be sure it works. And I like the convenience of seeing the full config file while hacking in it. Also, systemctl manage itself the dir creation, and the daemon-reload. Thanks DigitalOceanTeam (digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/…) Merci Alexandre ;)

Comment: Still working on Debian Stretch. Mans getting mad rep for fixing this one. Cheers boy.

Comment: @AlexandreMélard Your comment about the username:password is correct.  I would add that if there are any special characters then you need to use unicode to replace them.  For example, for `http://user:p@ssw0rd!@ip:80` you would put `http://user:p%40ssw0rd%21@ip:80`.  Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I tried to fix the half-broken link. Can you review it and see if it is OK (the original page redirects, etc.)?

Comment: This method worked! The ~/.docker/config.json method and other options did not work for me on Docker 1.13 with Redhat 7.6.

Comment: Worked on Linux Mint 19.1!! Why setting proxy in `~/.docker/config.json` or as environmental variables doesn't work?

Comment: Success on Fedora 29. Instructions on https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy don't work (350 Downvotes there).

Comment: First I tried to put an https proxy setting into the same file and that blew it. But with only the http proxy line it works. :)

Comment: Would it work if the docker is not running as a service. If its installed via binaries

Comment: Worked on  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: For docker installed through snap, the folder should be `/etc/systemd/system/snap.docker.dockerd.service.d`, and restart with `sudo systemctl restart snap.docker.dockerd.service`

Comment: Still the correct solution on (k)ubuntu 21.10. I don't understand, why the official solution on docs.docker.com ([link](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)) still doesn't work or is modified.

Comment: in case it helps someone,  just as a side comment,  it's important that both HTTP and HTTPS vars are defined for this solution to work.

Comment: Works on CentOS7. Thanks for saving my day

Answer (score 97):

Your APT proxy settings are not related to Docker.

Docker uses the HTTP_PROXY environment variable, if present. For example:

```
sudo HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.1:3128/ docker pull busybox
```

But instead, I suggest you have a look at your `/etc/default/docker`configuration file: you should have a line to uncomment (and maybe adjust) to get your proxy settings applied automatically. Then restart the Docker server:

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: In my case /etc/default/docker contained lowercased example (http_proxy), but to have things working I had to add uppercased setting (HTTP_PROXY) there.

Comment: you shouldn't set the HTTP_PROXY for the docker client

Comment: Does not work with docker 1.9.1, instead see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28093517/2091399) below

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 14.04 when installing docker from apt.dockerproject.org.

Comment: This does not work on Debian 8.8, and you need to set http_proxy in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d as shown in the accepted answer

Answer (score 64):

On CentOS the configuration file for Docker is at:

> `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

Adding the below line helped me to get the Docker daemon working behind a proxy server:

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
```

Comment: export HTTP_PROXY="http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>" for those behind corporate proxies

Comment: for me this worked ONLY without the `export`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: For me `export` only works on CentOS6 and w/o on CentOS7

Comment: On Centos7 I also had to not use export

Comment: `export HTTP_PROXY=...` is a Bashism, for non-Bash shells (such as what /bin/sh may be), use two lines `HTTP_PROXY=...` and then `export HTTP_PROXY`     That said, I didn't need the `export` at all.

Comment: Do not forget to restart docker service, after change this setting : `service docker restart`

Comment: Tried several approaches, this works for me on my Centos7.

Answer (score 50):

If you're using the new **Docker for Mac** (or **Docker for Windows**), just right-click the Docker tray icon and select *Preferences* (Windows: Settings), then go to Advanced, and under Proxies specify your proxy settings there. Click *Apply and Restart* and wait until Docker restarts.

Comment: In case someone uses a locally-bound proxy (e.g. _127.0.0.1:8787_) on macOS like me, here's the more detailed setup guide: [Why a locally-bound proxy doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41544629/2293304)

Comment: I have set my proxies via windows:settings but these proxies are not propagating to my containers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272933/docker-at-windows-10-proxy-propagation-to-containers-not-working

Comment: For me i needed only to put in my DNS Server and it worked then. Thanks.

Comment: Oh thank you this was driving me insane.

Answer (score 31):

On Ubuntu you need to set the http_proxy for the Docker daemon, not the client process. This is done in `/etc/default/docker` (see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/gRXMTCLcRE0/4XIg49FyQFUJ)).

Comment: it says that I don't have permission to access your group. In the link.

Comment: I don't think this works for Ubuntu 18.04 and above.

Answer (score 29):

To extend [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy/24277694#24277694), for this to work in CentOS 7, I had to remove the "export" commands. So edit

```
/etc/sysconfig/docker
```

And add:

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
HTTPS_PROXY="https://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
http_proxy="${HTTP_PROXY}"
https_proxy="${HTTPS_PROXY}"
```

Then restart Docker:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

The [source is this blog post](http://robwin.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/running-docker-on-centos-behind-proxy.html).

Comment: Only HTTP_PROXY is required (tested on Fedora 20).

Answer (score 14):

## Why a locally-bound proxy doesn't work

### The Problem

If you're running a *locally-bound* proxy, e.g. listening on *`127.0.0.1:8989`*, it WON'T WORK in **Docker for Mac**. From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/):

> ### I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). Our current recommendation is to attach an unused IP to the `lo0` interface on the Mac; for example: `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24`, and make sure that your service is listening on this address or `0.0.0.0` (ie not `127.0.0.1`). Then containers can connect to this address.

The similar is for Docker server side. (To understand the server side and client side of Docker, try to run `docker version`.) And the server side runs on a virtualization layer which has its own `localhost`. Therefore, it won't connect to the proxy server on the `localhost` of the host OS.

### The solution

So, if you're using a locally-bound proxy like me, basically you would have to do the following things to make it work with Docker for Mac:

1. Make your proxy server listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. ***Caution:*** you'll need proper firewall configuration to prevent malicious access to it.
2. Add a loopback alias to the `lo0` interface, e.g. *`10.200.10.1/24`*:

   ```
    sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24
   ```
3. Set HTTP and/or HTTPS proxy to *`10.200.10.1:8989`* from *Preferences* in Docker tray menu (assume that the proxy server is listening on port *`8989`*).

After that, test the proxy settings by running a command in a new container from an image which is not downloaded:

```
$ docker rmi -f hello-world
  ...

$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

c04b14da8d14: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0256e8a36e2070f7bf2d0b0763dbabdd67798512411de4cdcf9431a1feb60fd9
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
  ...
```

***Notice:*** the loopback alias set by `ifconfig` does not preserve after a reboot. To make it persistent is another topic. Please check [this blog post](http://kanonji.info/blog/2016/01/28/assign-ip-address-to-loopback-adapter-on-mac/) in Japanese (Google Translate may help).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been trying to find a solution for the last year or so with to get SquidMan on the Mac when trying to access both work and outside network through the company proxy.

I got this to stick around by hooking it into launchd to be configured at startup.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: Thank's man. I finally found your post! It works. If you are using cntlm don't forget to add the binding 0.0.0.0 to your configuration. e.g. Listen 0.0.0.0: 8989

Comment: i'm using cntlm too, and change it to gateway mode

Answer (score 13):

This is the fix that worked for me: Ubuntu, Docker version: 1.6.2

In the file `/etc/default/docker`, add the line:

```
export http_proxy='http://<host>:<port>'
```

Restart Docker

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Working on Docker v1.12.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and Mint 17.3

Comment: Works for 14.04.4 + Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Answer (score 11):

To configure Docker to work with a proxy you need to add the HTTPS_PROXY / HTTP_PROXY environment variable to the Docker sysconfig file (`/etc/sysconfig/docker`).

Depending on if you use `init.d` or the services tool you need to add the "export" statement (due to *[Debian Bug report logs - #767441. Examples in /etc/default/docker are misleading regarding the supported syntax](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767441)*):

```
HTTPS_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
HTTP_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
export HTTP_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
```

The Docker repository (Docker Hub) only supports HTTPS. To get Docker working with SSL intercepting proxies you have to add the proxy root certificate to the systems trust store.

For CentOS, copy the file to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and update the CA trust store and restart the Docker service.

If your proxy uses NTLMv2 authentication - you need to use intermediate proxies like [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) to bridge the authentication. [This blog post explains it in detail](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/11/using-docker-with-a-proxy.html).

Answer (score 7):

After installing Docker, do the following:

```
[mdesales@pppdc9prd1vq ~]$ sudo HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy02.ie.xyz.net:80 ./docker -d &
[2] 20880
```

Then, you can pull or do anything:

```
mdesales@pppdc9prd1vq ~]$ sudo docker pull base
2014/04/11 00:46:02 POST /v1.10/images/create?fromImage=base&tag=
[/var/lib/docker|aa088847] +job pull(base, )
Pulling repository base
b750fe79269d: Download complete
27cf78414709: Download complete
[/var/lib/docker|aa088847] -job pull(base, ) = OK (0)
```

Answer (score 6):

In the new version of Docker, **docker-engine**, in a **systemd** based distribution, you should add the environment variable line to */lib/systemd/system/docker.service*, as it is mentioned by others:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://hostname_or_ip:port/"
```

Comment: This was needed on RHEL7.

Comment: add the line to the [Service] section

Answer (score 4):

As I am not allowed to comment yet:

For CentOS 7 I needed to activate the EnvironmentFile within "docker.service" like it is described here: [Control and configure Docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/).

Edit: I am adding my solution as stated out by Nilesh. I needed to open "/etc/systemd/system/docker.service" and I had to add within the section

> [Service]
>
> EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker

Only then was the file "etc/sysconfig/docker" loaded on my system.

Answer (score 4):

If using socks5 proxy, here is my test with Docker 17.03.1-ce with setting "all_proxy", and it worked:

```
# Set up socks5 proxy server
ssh sshUser@proxyServer -C -N -g -D \
     proxyServerIp:9999 \
     -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
     -o ServerAliveInterval=60

# Configure dockerd and restart.
# NOTICE: using "all_proxy"
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf <<EOF
[Service]
Environment="all_proxy=socks5://proxyServerIp:9999"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,private.docker.registry.com"
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker

# Test whether can pull images
docker run -it --rm alpine:3.5
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem with curl in Docker build, I added the following inside the Dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy=http://infoprx2:8080
ENV https_proxy=http://infoprx2:8080
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim
```

Note that the ENV statement is BEFORE the RUN statement.

And in order to make the Docker daemon able to access the Internet (I use Kitematic with boot2docker), I added the following into `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://infoprx2:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://infoprx2:8080
```

Then I restarted Docker with `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`.

Answer (score 3):

The complete solution for Windows, to configure the proxy settings.

```
< user>:< password>@< proxy-host>:< proxy-port>
```

You can configure it directly by right-clicking on settings, in the Docker icon, and then Proxies.

There you can configure the proxy address, port, user name, and password.

In this format:

```
< user>:< password>@< proxy-host>:< proxy-port>
```

Example:

```
"geronimous:mypassword@192.168.44.55:8080"
```

Nothing more than this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Ubuntu, you should execute this command:

```
export https_proxy=http://your_name:password@ip_proxy:port docker
```

And reload Docker with:

```
service docker.io restart
```

Or go to `/etc/docker.io` with nano...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to set up lowercase variables. In my case, my **/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf** file looks like this:

```
[Service]
Environment="ftp_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/"
Environment="http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/"
Environment="https_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/"
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Ubuntu, execute these commands to add your proxy.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/docker
```

And uncomment the lines that specifies

```
#export http_proxy = http://username:password@10.0.1.150:8050
```

And replace it with your appropriate proxy server and username.

Then restart Docker using:

```
service docker restart
```

Now you can run Docker commands behind proxy:

```
docker search ubuntu
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue behind a firewall. Follow the below steps:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@IP:port/"
```

Don’t use or remove the https_prxoy.conf file.

Reload and restart your Docker container:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2557*********************************8
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting proxy environment variables did not help me in version 1.0.1... I had to update the `/etc/default/docker.io` file with the correct value for the "http_proxy" variable.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) with Docker 1.9.1, I just uncommented the `http_proxy` line, updated the value and then restarted the Docker service.

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.server.com:80"
```

and then

```
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but might help, especially if you don't want to deal with service files.

In case you are the one is hosting the image, one way is to convert the image as a tar archive instead, using something like the following **at the server**.

```
docker save <image-name> --output <archive-name>.tar
```

Simply download the archive and turn it back into an image.

```
docker load <archive-name>.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove proxy from environment variables

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset no_proxy
```

and then restart your docker

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo HTTP_PROXY=http://<IP address of proxy server:port> docker -d &
```

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL6.6 only this works (note the use of `export`):

**/etc/sysconfig/docker**

```
export http_proxy="http://myproxy.example.com:8080"
export https_proxy="http://myproxy.example.com:8080"
```

NOTE: Both can use the `http` protocol.)

Thanks to https://crondev.com/running-docker-behind-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

In my network, Ubuntu works behind a corporate ISA proxy server. And it requires authentication. I tried all the solutions mentioned above and nothing helped. What really helped was to write a proxy line in file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf` without a domain name.

Instead of

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user@domain:password@proxy:8080"
```

or

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\user:password@proxy:8080"
```

and some other replacement such as `@ -> %40` or `\ -> \\` I tried to use

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:8080"
```

And it works now.

Answer (score 0):

### Have resolved the issue by following the below steps:

step 1: `sudo systemctl start docker`

step 2: `sudo systemctl enable docker`
(Created symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.)

step 3: `sudo systemctl status docker`

step 4: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`

step 5: `sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf`

**Set proxy as below**

```
[Service]

Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:80"

Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:80"

Environment="NO_PROXY=.proxy.server.com,*.proxy.server.com,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

step 6: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

step 7: `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`

step 8: `vi /etc/environment and source /etc/environment`

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:80
https_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:80
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:80
no_proxy=127.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8,3.0.0.0/8,localhost,*.abc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like I needed to use  proxy to use google's dns for project's dependency and for API request needed to communicate with a private server at the same time.

For RHEL7 I configured the system like this:

went to the directory /etc/sysconfig/docker

```
Environment=http_proxy="http://ip:port"
Environment=https_proxy="http://ip:port"
Environment=no_proxy="hostname"
```

then save the file and use the command :

> sudo systemctl restart docker

after that configure your Dockerfile :
setup the environment structure first:

```
ENV http_proxy http://ip:port
ENV https_proxy http://ip:port
ENV no_proxy "hostname"
```

that's all! :)