# Docker Ubuntu Behind Proxy

Tags: docker

Looking at docs there is no instruction on how to run it behind a proxy.
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

Reading on forums, the instruction is to update /etc/default/docker to export the proxy setup.

```
 export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
 export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
 export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
 export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
```

Then we restart/start docker

```
 sudo service docker start
```

Inside a container, if I run 'apt-get', npm install, bower install I cant get through the proxy.

Not sure what I m missing.

Comment: Inside the container `127.0.0.1` is going to point at the container itself. Probably not the IP you want here.

Comment: For future readers, it would be helpful to clarify in the question what kind of proxy and the purpose.  Because running a docker instance behind a reverse proxy is common, and it's not very obvious what the OP is trying to achieve.  Perhaps: "I want to be able to perform HTTP requests from the docker container, but need to go through a web proxy".

Comment: Check this link, it has every possible way specified very clearly: https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/docker_proxy.html

Answer (score 152):

#### Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

For `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` who uses `SysVinit`, you should modify `/etc/default/docker` file:

```
# cat /etc/default/docker
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#
#   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
#   https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/
#

.......
# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
export http_proxy="http://web-proxy.corp.xxxxxx.com:8080/"
export https_proxy="https://web-proxy.corp.xxxxxx.com:8080/"
......
```

Then restart `docker`:

```
service docker restart
```

#### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

For `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` who uses `Systemd`, you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy):

(1) Create a systemd drop-in directory:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

(2) Add proxy in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` file:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=https://web-proxy.corp.xxxxxx.com:8080/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://web-proxy.corp.xxxxxx.com:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

(3) Flush changes:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

(4) Restart Docker:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

[Official Reference](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: The path in Ubuntu 17.04 is /lib/systemd/system/docker.service

Comment: `Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/mongo/images: http: error connecting to proxy https://proxy-foo.com:80: dial tcp: lookup proxy-foo.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host`, I got this error on 16.04

Comment: Very nice! After a lot of search, this one worked! Other websites generally only provides configuration for Ubuntu 14.

Comment: This answer has worked very well forme.OP, please accept this answer or the other that worked for you. Please don't keep the questions opened for no reason.

Comment: Hello, I am using `sudo service docker start` to start docker, however it seems that it does not detect the proxy inside the http-proxy.conf file

Answer (score 25):

For Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
`Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-54-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 26 19:15:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Edit you `/etc/default/docker` file

```
sudo vim /etc/default/docker
```

Add this line at the bottom:

```
export http_proxy="http://PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT"
```

Restart the `docker` service

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try to add lines in `/etc/environment`:

```
https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128"
http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128"
ftp_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128"
no_proxy="127.0.0.1/8, localhost, 192.168.0.0/16"
```

it will be useful for all services on your Linux system

Then edit `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.
In the end of the `[Service]` section, add line:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

And then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Comment: I like this method the best.  However, before restarting the service I had to run 'systemctl daemon-reload'

Answer (score 4):

systemctl will have to installed, which can be problematic.
In case /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf or /etc/default/docker solution does not work for you, simply use the below command:

`docker build [OPTIONS] PATH --build-arg http_proxy=http://your.proxy:port --build-arg https_proxy=http://your.proxy:port --build-arg no_proxy=.internal.domain,localhost,127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

An interesting issue about the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY is that: if your password has a special char like "$", "%", then it will not be processed correctly by the docker daemon when you execute command like: dock run xxx, you will encounter error. Then you can try to set the special char to others, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)

Add to `~/.docker/config.json` proxy configuration

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `127.0.0.1` to your host IP or some public accessible IP

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but none of the solutions here worked for me because I am not running docker desktop. What worked is the one in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy). You need to make a file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` and specify proxies there

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP setup the proxy to docker but he is using ubuntu inside docker, He want to run apt-get, for that he need to setup the proxy again for apt-get

Run inside your ubuntu docker container the following command

```
nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

and then edit inside it the proxy configuration:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy.svr.com:1234";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxy.svr.com:1234";
```

As mention on other anwers, if your proxy require auth and your password have special characters, you need to URL escaped then.

There is an example for auth:

```
username: u$3er_n@m3
password: p@$$w+rd
domain: domain

Acquire::http::proxy "http://domain%5Cpega%5Cu%243er_n%40m3:p%40%24%24w%2Brd@proxy.svr.com:1234";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://domain%5Cpega%5Cu%243er_n%40m3:p%40%24%24w%2Brd@proxy.svr.com:1234";
```