# Make docker use proxy to download dependencies when build image

Tags: docker

Out application use gradle as the build tool and we use gitlab-ci to build docker image once a tag is created.

Now once the gitlab-runner try to  build  the image, it have to download dependencies from the mave repo however we can not access the repo directly, so we have to use a proxy.

The gitlab-runner machine is Ubuntu 18.04, after google we found a lot of similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550360/docker-ubuntu-behind-proxy) we have tried the following to config the proxy;

1 /etc/environment

2 ~/.docker/config.json

3 /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

However none of them takes effect, what is going on?

BTW, we do not want to config the proxy in the gitlab-ci.yml or somewhere in the source codes since we think the proxy problem should be solved in the server where the gitlab-runner run.