# why did the pulling process in docker act like this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, firewall, agent

I just want to pull the ubuntu image from the docker's repository:

```
pete@pete-Aspire-4750:~$ sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo "hello world"    
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:14.04' locally
ubuntu:14.04: The image you are pulling has been verified
53f858aaaf03: Downloading 57.31 MB/197.2 MB 1h57m42s
837339b91538: Download complete
615c102e2290: Download complete
b39b81afc8ca: Download complete     
511136ea3c5a: Already exists
```

then nothing happened! is it beacause I'm in China ,so I can't get the image behind the greatwall?
or something else?

Comment: you are missing the -t options for tags

Comment: @c4f4t0r I reckon that could be the real root cause!! Let's see.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it was caused by poor download speed, was never really a problem with the tool in the first place

Comment: yes,I was so careless that I ignored the first downloading information

Answer (score 1):

The output says that the download is complete. You can do a check by issuing the command `sudo docker images`. It will list the downloaded images like given below.

```
REPOSITORY       TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED      VIRTUAL SIZE   
ubuntu           13.10    5e019ab7bf6d  4 weeks ago  180 MB
```

Comment: REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              511136ea3c5a        19 months ago       0 B
pete@pete-Aspire-4750:~$ sudo docker pull ubuntu:14.04
Repository ubuntu already being pulled by another client. Waiting.

Comment: It seems yout first `docker pull ubuntu` has not completed yet. Try again when `sudo docker images` shows (more or less) a size of 199.3 MB (that is what I have for 14.04).

Comment: yes,I agree.
but it's so weird that I've been waiting for 3 more hours.....
maybe i have to wait longer.......

Comment: It just finished......I think maybe just beacuse of my poor bandwidth
really thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I'm speculating that it did work. The "hello world" should have appeared at the end. Did you try running the command a second time? Now that the image has been downloaded you should see the result immediately.

Don't forget every time you run the command you're creating a container instance. These will accumulate locally:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
9a31ad292a0a        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/echo 'hello wo   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       ecstatic_darwin     
035cf18ee6a2        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/echo 'hello wo   3 minutes ago        Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                            sick_hawking
```

A better way to issue the run command is to include the "--rm" option which will automatically delete the container instance when your finishing with them

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo "hello world" 
hello world
```

Hope this helps.

## Networking

Downloading images behind firewalls is not uncommon, but your error message would explicitly show failures (Your output shows "Download complete" messages). This is normally fixed by setting the http proxy environment variable. See:

- [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)