# Pull docker image behind a corporate firewall throws "Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer"

Tags: proxy, docker, firewall, http-proxy

I can't download images behind the corporate firewall.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy) helped me to fix the ***no address associated with hostname*** error. I use Cntlm for proxy user authentication.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

$ docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

$ sudo docker search ubuntu
Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=ubuntu: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: No address associated with hostname
$ sudo mv /tmp/http-proxy.conf /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf 
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128/"

$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ sudo docker search ubuntu | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
NAME                              DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
esycat/ubuntu                     Ubuntu LTS                                      0                    [OK]
```

The pull request interacts with the server, finds the endpoint and fails with: ***Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer***.

```
$ sudo docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu

fcee8bcfe180: Pulling fs layer 
4cdc0cbc1936: Pulling fs layer 
d9e545b90db8: Pulling fs layer 
c4bea91afef3: Pulling fs layer 
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ubuntu
af88597ec24b: Pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/ubuntu, endpoint: https://registry-1.docker.iaf88597ec24b: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/ubuntu, endpoint: https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (895b070402bd7d26d9595e939422c598e8cc1f4adaf88597ec24b: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/ubuntu, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (895b070402bd7d26d9595e939422c598e8cc1f4ade1b34e2a9659138ffe3c5c9) 

Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/ubuntu, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (895b070402bd7d26d9595e939422c598e8cc1f4ade1b34e2a9659138ffe3c5c9)
```

Any idea why the pull request fails? Does a pull request use a *different* port and/or protocol? Is something *missing* in my configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last days, I figured out that ***Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer*** is a generic error message for any kind of network issues. It can point to an [incorrect DNS server](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18293) or missing SSL certificates.

I solved it by [updating all SSL certificates](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) with latest and restarting docker.