# Unable to find image error, How to setup proxy to download images

Tags: docker

I need setup the corporation proxy in order Docker can download the images from public registry.

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world 
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally 
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world 
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy) but `systemctl` is not present in Ubuntu 12.04. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Post it as answer and I will accept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Ubuntu only**

Edit `/etc/defaults/docker.io` and add the following lines:

```
export http_proxy='http://user:password@proxy-host:proxy-port'
```

Then restart docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker.io restart
```

Comment: There is no `/etc/defaults/` directory.  Maybe you mean `/etc/default/` . Also there is no `docker.io` service, but maybe you have a different Ubuntu version (I have bionic LTS 18.04.4)

Answer (score 4):

From Docker official documentation,

Create a `systemd` drop-in directory for the docker service:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
```

If you have internal Docker registries that you need to contact without proxying you can specify them via the `NO_PROXY` environment variable:

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

**Flush changes:**

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
```

Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the following error while trying to run the hello-world container

```
$docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.205.194.204:443: getsockopt: no route to host.
```

I tried the steps in the following link which worked for me with respect to HTTPS or HTTP configuration

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS, what works for me is to add this line to `/etc/sysconfig/docker`:

```
http_proxy=your_proxy:port
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proxy for both docker server (docker-machine) and docker client (docker).

**Set proxy for docker-machine:**
I think you can specify this when creating the machine, see [docker/toolbox#102 (comment)](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/102#issuecomment-131715272)

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080 \
--engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://example.com:8080 \
--engine-env NO_PROXY=example2.com \
default
```

**Set Proxy for docker (client)**

*Windows*

```
set http_proxy=http://example.com:8080
set https_proxy=https://example.com:8080
```

*Linux*

```
export http_proxy=http://example.com:8080
export https_proxy=https://example.com:8080
```

Answer (score -1):

In-spite of adding the proxy, docker version "18.06.0" dosn't work, however the lower version of the docker works fine.

**Edit 1**: Re-installing docker-ce will work !!