# Proxy configuration for OpenShift Origin

Tags: rhel, openshift-origin

I am setting up an OpenShift origin server. The configurations I do heavily relies on the walkthrough description:

> https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/sample-app/README.md

After creating a project, I add a new app like this (successfully):

> oc new-app centos/ruby-22-centos7~https://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world.git

OpenShift tries to build immediatelly, only to fail as follows:

> F0222 15:24:58.504626       1 builder.go:204] Error: build error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection refused

I consulted the documentation about the proxy configuration:

> https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/http_proxies.html#git-repository-access

Concluded that I can simply edit the YAML descriptor **for this specific app** to include my corporate proxy.

```
...
source:
  type: Git
  git:
    uri: "git://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world.git"
    httpProxy: http://proxy.example.com
    httpsProxy: https://proxy.example.com
...
```

With that change the build proceeds.

Can the HTTP proxy be configured system wide?

**Note**: again, I simply downloaded the binaries (client, server), did not install via ansible. And I did not find relevant properties *openshift.local.config* folder, inside my server binary folder.

Comment: Small update: I just realized that I have to generate the configurations at first, using write-config. I have to check if then I can configure the proxy in the master-config.yaml. Res: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/master_node_configuration.html#creating-new-configuration-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I now know enough to answer my own question.
There are two places where one needs to deal with corporate proxy settings.

**Docker**
This thread will tell you what to do in detail:

> [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

In my case on RHEL 7.2 I needed to edit this file: /etc/sysconfig/docker
I had to add the following entries:

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.company.com:4128"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.company.com:4128"
```

Then a restart of the docker service was necessary.

**Origin Proxy**
What I missed originally was the place to configure our corporate proxy settings. Currently I have a cluster (1 master, 1 node) installed via ansible.

These are the relevant files to edit on the servers:
* /etc/sysconfig/origin-master
* /etc/sysconfig/origin-node

There already placeholders in this file:

```
#NO_PROXY=master.example.com
#HTTP_PROXY=http://USER:PASSWORD@IPADDR:PORT
#HTTPS_PROXY=https://USER:PASSWORD@IPADDR:PORT
```

Documentation:

> https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/http_proxies.html