# Cannot download docker images behind proxy : Timeout : Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Getting following error:

Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/graphana/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.

Already tried solution provided in following links (though they are for ubuntu):

[Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to this when browsing through the Docker for Mac forums:

https://forums.docker.com/t/beta-13-didnt-work-with-local-proxy/13569/10 (a BIG thanks to onigoetz!)

I am using CNTLM on my machine running on port 3128, so using the following settings worked for me:

[image: Docker for Mac proxy settings: use http://192.168.65.1:3128]

- **192.168.65.1** because that is the IP address of your computer on the Docker virtual network, and
- **3128** because that is the port I am running CNTLM on.

After applying these settings and restarting Docker, I was able to successfully pull a Docker image through the proxy.

Comment: thanks for reply. Where did you find these settigs for me thee option are not coming.

Comment: never mind. I was running old version of Docker for mac.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work for you.  Perhaps you could update your question with more information to make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: I got the same error.  Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/graphana/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.