# Docker for windows 7- Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/tags/latest: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: windows, docker

When I try to run a hello-world docker image, as to test if my newly installed docker is working I get this error Docker for windows 7- Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/tags/latest: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

I am using Windows 7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oypto.png)

Comment: Do you have a proxy or web filter that is inspecting https traffic?

Comment: I think so, one of my collegues was able to pull the hello-world container. I am not sure if we have different network settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I wwas connected to the company LAN instead of the WIFI. They seemed to have different protocols and Internet rules.