# Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/centos on Redhat Enterprise Linux behind proxy server

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have installed and pulled from docker.io successfully many times on Redhat Enterprise Linux. But now I am having a very difficult time with a slightly different environment behind a proxy server.

I am starting to think there is a modification Redhat has done to the docker packages preventing my proxy setting from working correctly. When I try to do a simple "docker pull centos", I get the frustrating error: "Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/centos".  I have tried other tags as well with no luck. Before I put the proxy setting in, I received "authorizationrequired" messages. I got past that by adding the proxy info to /etc/sysconfig/docker. Then I received x509 errors. I got past that by adding the appropriate certificate file to docker. Now, with everything seemingly correct, I am unable to do a simple pull. From what I can tell, this is not an issue with stock docker. Is there something else that needs to be done to make the redhat docker package work with a proxy? Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried everything in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy) to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried everything in that post to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looked like it was working from the cli. However, I ran /var/log/messages | grep docker to look at the docker daemon logs. I was still getting certificate errors. I loaded hub.docker.com into my browser and extracted the certificate chain. I put those in /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.io and it worked part-way.

I needed to add those proxy certs to the global location and now it works all the way.