# Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally Docker

Tags: docker

This is the first time I am trying to set up docker (version 17.09.0-ce). I have followed the all instructions from official site and this run ok on my machine (Windows 10 x64). When I type `docker --version` on console returns `Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4`. But i am trying execute `docker run -t hello-world` and this is the answer:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

my internet is from proxy, but I make a VPN and everything work perfectly except docker, I even install python packages using pip. what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the docker daemon process is using this VPN/proxy setup? When you run `docker run` that is a client process talking to the docker daemon over a named pipe (on Windows), and then the docker daemon actually tries to make the network connection to pull content from the Docker registry (registry-1.docker.io). You may need to validate that the Docker engine/daemon is able to reach the internet to solve this issue (e.g. it is probably running as a service and may need environment configuration for the VPN?)

Comment: @PhilE and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Found an answer for a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this modifing `daemon.json` and put my proxy there. In case of Windows on Docker Desktop, go to Resources, Proxies:

[image: docker desktop proxy config]

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue on windows 10 by resetting the DNS server to use the Google DNS fixed address: 8.8.8.8 ([docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#network))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve the issues for most.

For windows behind a proxy, you can do the followings to resolve this issue
go to your proxy setting under resources and enter your proxy credentials
`username:password@yourdomain:port`.

Important make sure to account for special character Unicode conversion
for example, if you have # in your password then you replace it with: `%23`
you can covert special characters via [site](https://unicodelookup.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For users in China, I recommand [this answer](https://blog.csdn.net/TommyXu8023/article/details/113291112).

You need to add a valid address to pull the image "hello-world".