# Docker at Windows 10 proxy propagation to containers not working

Tags: docker, proxy, windows-10, containers

I am behind cooperate proxy and running docker on windows 10. I have setup the proxy on docker as per the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#proxies).

[image: my docker proxy settings]

I am able to pull images but these proxy settings are not propagating to containers e.g. when I run alpine env, it does not show proxy conf. Below is my output

```
λ docker run alpine env                                          
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  HOSTNAME=14fca5bee12f                                            
  HOME=/root
```

Following is the expected output as per the documentation.

[image: exptected output]

On building following docker file, I get connection errors from alpine container

**Docker Version**

```
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD HelloWorld.class HelloWorld.class
RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "HelloWorld"]
```

**Error**

```
Step 3/4 : RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre                                                                      
 ---> Running in 1205b24d5044                                                                                     
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                       
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main: could not connect to server (check repositories file)      
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.70c88391.tar.gz: No such file or directory                                             
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                  
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community: could not connect to server (check repositories file) 
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.5022a8a2.tar.gz: No such file or directory                                             
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:                                                                                 
  openjdk8-jre (missing):                                                                                         
    required by: world[openjdk8-jre]                                                                              
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update add openjdk8-jre' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Passing Proxy as build-arg**

I tried the following command and it worked. Is there any other way to automatically propagate the proxy settings as mentioned in documentation (see link above)

```
docker build --tag "docker-hello-world:latest" . --build-arg http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@proxy_address:proxy_port/ --build-arg https_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@proxy_address:proxy_port/ --build-arg no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Comment: You don't mention your `docker version`.

Comment: updated the post with docker version

Comment: Did you use _Use system proxies_ (if available) or _Manual proxy configuration_?

Comment: I have set the proxy on docker settings as mentioned in https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#proxies
Plus I have also set system environment variables named proxy and https_proxy

Comment: There are three options in the dialog. Can you confirm that _Manual proxy configuration_ is not working?

Comment: @javabrett Yes, I have selected the Manual proxy configuration option and have provided proxy address in http://<username>:<password>@proxy_address:proxy_port/ format.

Comment: Please open an issue at <https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues>. Source: <https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24697#issuecomment-358154189>.

Comment: Is there any alternative to manually set proxy settings in docker? or Not expose credentials with Proxy settings?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Pulling images was working but provisioning a container was not working. In this case the solution was to provide Docker with a configuration file named `~/.docker/config.json` with the following contents.

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://proxy.server....com:8080",
     "httpsProxy": "https://proxy.server.....com:8080"
   }
 }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled making it work but finally found a working solution on my side.

I'm behind a corporate proxy and have a CNTLM properly configured on windows and linked in my docker desktop settings with address `127.0.0.1:3128`. My docker runs under WSL2.

The magic tip hereis to link your containers proxies to docker internal proxy `host.docker.internal`.

I didn't find why I wasn't able to connect with the localhost proxy (`127.0.0.1:3128`) like i did for docker desktop config, i guess docker runs an internal proxy as a gateway to access windows network.