# Proxy Settings for Docker Private Registry in VMs

Tags: docker, proxy, virtual-machine, docker-registry

Hi folks and colleagues I'm running out of ideas.

My main problem is that my docker client VM can't connect to the private registry in another VM and throws the error:

> user@ubuntu:~$ docker push 192.168.14.147:5000/hello-world
>   The push refers to repository [192.168.14.147:5000/hello-world]
>   Get https://192.168.14.147:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

My current setup:

- One VM (Ubuntu 16.03) where I run my docker registry on port 5000 (VM-IP: 192.168.14.147)
- When I tried to push/pull on the registry VM with
  `docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world` it pushes and pulls the tagged image correct, so the registry is working
- One VM (Ubuntu 16.03) where I run my docker "client" and want to push/pull (VM-IP: 192.168.14.148)
- I can contact both VM successful via `ping 192.168.14.147` (.148) in the terminal
- Both VMs have following (fully working) proxy settings provided via bash script:

> ```
> echo "export http_proxy=http://10.8.31.1:8080
> export https_proxy=http://10.8.31.1:8080" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
> echo "export http_proxy=http://10.8.31.1:8080
> export https_proxy=http://10.8.31.1:8080" >> /etc/environment
> echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://10.8.31.1:8080\";
> Acquire::https::Proxy \"http://10.8.31.1:8080\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
> ```

and the (working) Docker Environment is specified as

```
 echo "[Service]
 Environment=\"HTTP_PROXY=http://10.8.31.1:8080/\""  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
 touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf
 echo "[Service]
 Environment=\"HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.8.31.1:8080/\""  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf
```

- Both VM are running on on the same host machine
- Self signed certificates are provided following this [guide](http://zacharykeeton.com/docker-private-registry/)

At home I cloned this setup without the proxy and it works very well. so it seems to be a lack of knowledge regarding the network/proxy issue and not the certificates.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy) in the docker http(s)-proxy.conf

`[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.8.31.1:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=192.168.14.147"`

because maybe it's forwarded to the proxy and can't find the registry IP there but that didn't work.

I invested a lot of effort in this topic and any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to access `curl https://192.168.14.147:5000/v2/_catalog`  from the VM?

Comment: Hi, curl doesn't work either. I get a: `user@ubuntu:~$ curl https://192.168.14.147:5000/v2/_catalog
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT` Do you have further hints I can check? Thx