# docker pull fails with error "Error while pulling image: connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, docker

## docker pull rhel7:7.3

Pulling repository docker.io/library/rhel7

> Error while pulling image: Get
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/rhel7/images: read tcp
>   X.X.X.X:33074->52.44.135.200:443: read: connection reset by peer

[Both docker run -it & docker pull is giving the same error]

Hi all,

I am trying to pull a docker image and seeing the above mentioned error.
My Linux server is behind a proxy.

I tried topi ng google.com to ensure I have connectivity to internet and that worked as well.

## ping google.com

```
PING google.com (172.217.3.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=15.9 ms
^C
```

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms

Any suggestions to fix this issue please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate case. Yes, the link you specified fixed the issue.