# How fix EOF during docker push command?

Tags: java, maven, docker, eof, maven-docker-plugin

I am trying to push docker image via [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven). Just couple of hours everything works but know I got enexception:

```
    [INFO] Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
    [INFO] 
    [ERROR] Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF
    [WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
    org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:185)
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute(BuildMojo.java:105)
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:253)
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.handleError(LoggingProgressHandler.java:105)
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.progress(LoggingProgressHandler.java:63)
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1441)
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1400)
        at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:178)
        ... 26 more
```

What does this error means? How to fix it?

**UPDATED**

Sometimes I got:

```
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/xenial: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fubuntu%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: EOF
```

Comment: I tried to access this url `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` and I got unauthorized. Maybe the EOF is due to authentication issues

Comment: May be but I did not change anytthing in configuration! E.g. this should happen every time of should not happen at all. But I have successful maven run just 15 minutes ago and failed it again.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? I found useful this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093517/9893722