# Why can't I download the artifactory image on docker hub?

Tags: image, docker

Artifactory supports an OSS docker image. I can access the official website by proxy, but I can't download the image. Every time I try to download an image using [the command from the official website](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Running+Artifactory+OSS)

> docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss

the download times out. Docker hub is okay.

Comment: What is bintray.io? Why are you using it?

Comment: That pull command may take a while but works for me and I didn't do any special configuration. The problem may be your internet connection.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with my agency service.I get it.thank you .

Comment: @ps4 Address given by official website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy may be of help

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, I am able to download using that same command. The problem is most likely due to your being behind a proxy. The steps to fix this will depend on your setup but there is useful advice in [Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your proxy as environment variables before pulling the image.

```
$ export http_proxy=http://your.proxy:80
$ export https_proxy=http://your.proxy:80
$ export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

After setting the proxies, you should be able to pull your image through the proxy:

`$ docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:4.16.0`