# Docker behind a proxy requires restart on boot

Tags: linux, docker, proxy

I apologise if I am posting this in the wrong section, I need some help and unsure where to turn to.

I am trying to run docker behind a proxy on a linux/ubuntu server machine. I have configured every proxy on the box (FTP/HTTPS/HTTP), I have also configured the Docker proxies mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093517/4261713

However, I have the docker service set to auto-start on machine boot, unless I log onto the machine and run `sudo service docker restart` those settings are ignored, and docker fails to use a proxy. This is all fine, we have a work around for local access, but I need to use this machine remotely using auto-builds/deployments etc. Therefore, the builds break without running that command.

Unfortunately I cannot get any help from Docker support, I have waited around 3 weeks for them to reply with no luck. This problem is more than likely me not understanding linux services/daemons. Can someone help me out?

To confirm what I have already tried:

1. I have created the http-proxy.conf in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and created the Environment variable there for the proxy.
2. I have tried to modify the docker service init.d file by adding to the `"DOCKER_OPTS"` variable at the top using `-e "HTTP_PROXY=http://addressofproxy:portofproxy" -e "HTTPS_PROXY=http://addressofproxy:portofproxy"` However, this also has made no difference and I still need to restart the service after a reboot!
3. EDIT: I have also set/configured the client config in `~/.docker/config.json` to have the proxies in. (as mentioned in the answers below by Kerat)

Any assistance is much appreciated, I am totally stuck with why it wont read the options in on startup.

Comment: @jww, i wasnt sure which of the sites to post to so went with "my usual digs", I shall move the question over there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a double instance installation. Confusingly ubuntu server comes with docker installed under package manager - snap, so installing under apt-get led to double installation.

I think this is a poor way to manage Ubuntu server, I would expect a plain, vanilla OS with nothing installed.. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to configure the proxy in `~/.docker/config.json` with :

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

as mentionned at https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client ?

Comment: yes I have, ill update the question to show this too