# Docker problem with sudo docker run hello-world: Gives Unable to find image error: Timeout

Tags: docker

I am new to programming and I am currently learning Django.
In the book I am reading now, it requires me to use Docker. I followed every step, installed Docker accordingly to the site information, but something doesn't seem to work. When I type in the console

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

this error comes up:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried a lot of things, reinstalled docker a few times, and installed it a different way, nothing seems to work! I am using Pop Os 19.04 which is kind of equal to Ubuntu 19.04. Please help!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I don't use proxy on my computer

Comment: Yes, I am currently answering from the computer I have the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me. He just changed the DNS settings for IPv4 and IPv6 and it all works now!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is some existing solution for the same issue as far i know there is some DNS configuration you need to perform.

I will suggest please check these

[stackoverflow #23111631 Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

[Github link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611)