# boot2docker vm forgets changes when restarted

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

Basically any changes I make while SSHed into the VM are lost at restart of the VM.  I am assuming the problem is associated with the error when I stop the VM.

```
C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker stop
error in run: Failed to stop machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

But, I may just be doing something dumb.

The sequence I followed is below (docker logo elided), you can see it losing the sample directory across the restart.

```
C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker up

Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start.......................ooo
Started.
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem
Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
    "boot2docker" ssh
to SSH into the VM instead.


C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker ssh
Boot2Docker version 1.5.0, build master : a66bce5 - Tue Feb 10 23:31:27 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef
docker@boot2docker:~$ ls
boot2docker, please format-me
docker@boot2docker:~$ mkdir testdir
docker@boot2docker:~$ ls
boot2docker, please format-me  testdir/
docker@boot2docker:~$ exit

C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker stop
error in run: Failed to stop machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1

C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker status
poweroff

C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker start
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
....................ooo
Started.
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\Tom\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem
Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
    "boot2docker" ssh
to SSH into the VM instead.


C:\Users\Tom>boot2docker ssh
Boot2Docker version 1.5.0, build master : a66bce5 - Tue Feb 10 23:31:27 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef
docker@boot2docker:~$ ls
boot2docker, please format-me
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

Running

- Windows: 8.1
- VirtualBox: 4.3.12 r93733
- Boot2Docker version 1.5.0, build master : a66bce5 - Tue Feb 10 23:31:27 UTC 2015
- Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what I explained in "[Windows Boot2Docker behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309)": there is no persistence in the **[Tiny Core](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/)** used by boot2docker as a Linux VM.

> You need to make sure the VirtualBox has the **[Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)** downloaded and added in the Virtual Box / File / Settings / Extension / add the `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.x.yy-zzzzz.vbox-extpack` file).
>
> As documented in boot2docker, you will have access (from your Tiny Core ssh session) to `/c/Users/<yourLogin>` (ie the `%USERPROFILE%` is shared by Virtual Box)

What I do in my [b2d.bat](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/b2d.bat) start script is copy the files I want to be restored (mainly docker `profile` or `.ashrc`, for http_proxy settings and favorite aliases), and keep all my other modifications in  `/c/Users/<yourLogin>`.