# Logstash in Docker - config file not found when mounted though a volume

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, logstash, boot2docker

**EDIT:** It seems to be a boot2docker thing... works fine in an ubuntu vm running docker.

I'm trying to fire up logstash in a Docker container but when I mount the config file as a volume, it doesn't seem to find it. Interestingly, if I start up the container with bash, I can see the config file in there and running the same command as what docker would, it works.

**Docker File**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER cvallance

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -yqq install openjdk-7-jre
RUN apt-get -yqq install curl
RUN mkdir /opt/logstash \
  && cd /opt/logstash \
  && curl -O https://download.elastic.co/logstash/logstash/logstash-1.4.2.tar.gz \
  && tar zxvf logstash-1.4.2.tar.gz

CMD ["/opt/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/bin/logstash", "agent", "--verbose", "-f", "/etc/logstash/sample.conf"]
```

**Config file located at `$(pwd)/config/sample.conf`**

```
input {
  stdin { }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

**Docker build command:**

```
docker build -t cvallance/logstash .
```

**Docker run command:**

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/config:/etc/logstash cvallance/logstash
```

**Error:**

```
Error: No config files found:  /etc/logstash/sample.conf
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?
```

**BUT** if I run the same command inside the container from a bash session like so...

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/config:/etc/logstash cvallance/logstash bash
...
root@d3fd885903dd:/# /opt/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/bin/logstash agent --verbose -f /etc/logstash/sample.conf
```

Everything works as expected. I.e. input and output

```
testing
{
       "message" => "testing",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-04-10T00:06:33.878Z",
          "host" => "d3fd885903dd"
}
```

Comment: side note: there's an official docker-library logstash image https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/logstash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a "boot2docker" thing, remember that is offers you a Linux host based on Tiny core, [**without any persistence**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507588/6309) (except `/var/lib/docker`).

What I do is make sure the [Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is installed, and get my `/c/Users/<yourLogin>` automatically shared in my boot2docker ssh session.
Whatever I need to keep is written there (`/c/Users/<yourLogin>/...`), not anywhere else.
If you have to mount a host directory as a data volume, you should mount a folder from `/c/Users/<yourLogin>/...`.

The other option (which does persists) is to define a [Data Volume Container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), which will persists data in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/conf.json`, and (for the actual files) in `/var/lib/docker/vfs/xxx`.
That is the preferred best-practice as it doesn't link your data container to a specific host platform (here '`/c/Users/<yourLogin>` actually depends on the *VM* host, on Windows! Not very portable.)