# Is it possible to have Docker On VM?

Tags: cloud, docker, hypervisor

I was thinking that whether we can have the docker on top of A guest OS.
The layered blueprint that i am thinking of is something like this
[image: Docker on Vm]

I will have my containers run on top of Docker and hence i feel can address the multi-os feature alongside Docker

Please suggest if such an implementation is possible or not?

Comment: This is a very common way to run Docker.  What made you think it might be difficult?

Comment: @Bryan : I am a complete novice on docker and was wondering if such a model was possible. Was working on the convergence of infrastructure using private cloud and hence was unaware that if we could really have docker on top of one of my instances created using Openstack. Community Guidance or example implementations was what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like **[boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/)** implements already, with:

- Host OS Windows or Mac
- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [Tiny Core](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/) as the host for Docker (meaning, no persistence except for `/var/lib/docker`, as [noted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554135/6309): use VirtualBox extension pack to mount your Guest Host home directory)
- [Docker](http://docs.docker.com/)

Comment: and in case of a type 1 hypervisor?

Comment: @gauravparashar the native or bare-metal hypervisor? http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/30/thinking-out-loud-does-docker-on-windows-matter/ mentions: "Azure could be made more relevant in the public cloud race through “native support for Docker containers” resulting in “native Type-1 hypervisor, native Docker containers.”"

Comment: @gauravparashar You also have the Xen project: https://xen-orchestra.com/blog/xen-and-docker-for-the-best/, mentioned in https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/cloud-computing/785769-containers-vs-hypervisors-the-battle-has-just-begun

Comment: @Bryan True. I have edited the answer accordingly. I also tried to explain those "nested" hosts in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309 (section "Hosts & Proxy: Windows => Boot2Docker => Docker Containers")

Comment: @VonC cool; I will delete my comment (and this one too, soon)