# Unable to access Docker containers folder on command line

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've just created my first docker container and it runs successfully. My problem now is that I can't access the folder where they are stored by default

`/var/lib/docker/containers`

It keeps throwing the error

`can't cd to containers`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need root to access it:

```
sudo ls /var/lib/docker/containers/
```

Without root access:

```
docker@boot2docker:/c/Users/VonC/prog/b2d$ cd /var/lib/docker/containers
-sh: cd: can't cd to /var/lib/docker/containers
```

So this would work:

```
docker@boot2docker:/c/Users/VonC/prog/b2d$ sudo su -
Boot2Docker version 1.6.0, build master : a270c71 - Thu Apr 16 19:50:36 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651
root@boot2docker:~# cd /var/lib/docker/containers/
root@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers#
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks! One more question, how do I export a container to use on another machine? Does that other (windows) machine need boot2docker installed in order to run that container?

Comment: @Danny You don't export container, but images. And yes, the other machine would need a recent Linux to run Docker containers, so for Windows, that would be boot2docker: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309

Comment: You should explore /var/lib/docker, depending upon your storage driver, you will find them in /var/lib/docker/aufs or var/lib/docker/devicemapper

Comment: @Danny you export images: you can archive an image as a tar and copy it that way (`docker export`: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#export)

Comment: @Danny a more sophisticated solution would involve a private image repo: http://blog.octo.com/en/docker-registry-first-steps/

Comment: Shouldn't there be some sort of usermod way to allow the user to access this content?

Comment: @tblev 6 years later, I still have to use `sudo` to access most parts of `/var/lib/docker`.

Comment: A cool way I've found is to use `docker logs <container_id>`.  It gives you the latest logs.  I wonder if you could tail it this way though..

Comment: [`docker logs --tail <container_id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) would tail the logs of a container indeed.