# Boot2docker proxy on Windows

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have installed boot2docker on Windows. I've tried to configure the proxy with the help of *https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/230*, but it didn't work.

When I execute `boot2docker download`, I get the following error:

```
boot2docker download
Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.6.0
Downloading boot2docker ISO image...
error in run: Failed to download ISO image: Get https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/14930729/0573f322-e442-11e4-8500-b1bbe904b032.iso?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dboot2docker.iso&response-content-type=application/octet-stream&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1430303112&Signature=oTercMri%2FkqD9cbA315JhNHzehk%3D:
Proxy Authentication Required
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See *"[How do I get Docker to run on a Windows system behind a corporate firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309)"*.

You need to set up:

- set `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` in your cmd session, in order for `boot2docker download` to work.
- (export) `http_proxy`, `http_proxy` and `no_proxy` in the `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` in order for a `docker search` (for example) to work.

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://<user>:<pwd>@proxy.company:80
  export https_proxy=http://<user>:<pwd>@proxy.company:80
  export no_proxy=.company,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,192.168.59.103
  ```

Comment: The directory structure `/var/lib/boot2docker` doesn't exist, should I create it?

Comment: It will exist in the boot2docker vm: read the link I mention: everything is detailed there. And the GitHub project b2d implements that.

Comment: I setup HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as env variables for my user that worked too.

Comment: You can set the proxy and the password in the Docker settings dialog via the Windows system tray. http://user:pw@proxy:1234

Comment: @Adam True. That didn't exist in April 2015 ;)

Answer (score 1):

VonC's solution worked for me. Other guides suggested using:

```
--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=...etc
```

In the docker-machine.exe, create a section of *start.sh*, but that didn't work for me. Adding the `export HTTP_PROXY` lines before the create line did the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by *"create a section of start.sh"*? And how can it be done in docker-machine.exe (presumably a binary file)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Docker create in a CMD windows like this (I'm using CNTLM, but it is the same idea):

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox 
  -engine-env HTTP_PROXY=[IP]:3128 
  -engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=[IP]:3128 
default
```

Some references that helped me a lot:

- *[How to install Docker on Windows behind a proxy](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-docker-on-windows-behind-a-proxy/)*
- *[Docker on Windows behind a Firewall](https://toedter.com/2015/05/11/docker-on-windows-behind-a-firewall/)*