# Is it possible to run docker client in window server as done in Windows 7?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

Presently is it possible to run docker client in Window Server2008 or 2012 
in similar line as done in Windows 7 and 8 ?
I know they have been working on window container as well hyper V container which is supposed to release in next version in 2016. but is there any way to use docker client in it directly presently ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can install VirtualBox on that Windows server, you can run the docker client (through boot2docker and its Tiny Core OS).

Since Windows Server 2008 is **[supported as a host server](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#hostossupport)**, the installation of boot2docker should be possible.
See also [How to get Docker to run on a Windows System behind a corporate firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309).

Comment: checl also this Microsoft link http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/06/23/docker-and-microsoft-announce-more-innovation-to-cross-platforms-and-win-hearts