# Boot2Docke init: boot2docker init error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

Trying

```
boot2docker init
```

as suggested in

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/436#issuecomment-50135355

but getting this error:

```
boot2docker init
error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Any idea what is happening and how to get rid of this error?

---

EDIT. I am using VirtualBox v4 as provided by Boot2Docker.

Comment: Please update your answer to clarify that you are not using VirtualBox 5.

Answer (score 1):

Boot2docker is currently not compatible with VirtualBox 5, see [Virtualbox 5.0 Compatibility](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/979).

A workaround is to use the current development version of docker-machine. On Mac OS, you can use [brew](http://brew.sh/) to install it:

```
$ brew install --HEAD docker-machine
$ docker-machine  -v
docker-machine version 0.4.0-dev (HEAD)
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox boot2docker
$ eval $( docker-machine env boot2docker )
$ docker version
```

Comment: I have never installed VB 5, my current version that came with Boot2Docker is 4.3.28

Comment: Nevertheless, you might try to use docker-machine instead of boot2docker. If you use VirtualBox 4, you can use the stable version, of course (omit `--HEAD` when installing with brew).

Comment: I actually did install `docker-machine`, which is however v 0.3.0 and is warned to be "experimental", so I presume v 0.4.0-dev is even more so. On the other hand, boot2docker is production-ready as far as I understand.

Comment: Not at all! From the [README](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#caveat-emptor) on GitHub: "Boot2Docker is currently designed and tuned for development. Using it for any kind of production workloads at this time is highly discouraged."

Comment: Ouch! At least it works now without errors, which I can't say about docker-machine, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to understand your answer - "A workaround" means only for VB5? What about VB4?

Comment: The workaround is mainly supposed to get you around the issue that boot2docker 1.7.0 is not compatible with VirtualBox 5. But, if you had any other issues with boot2docker, I would have suggested you try docker-machine, too. I personally tried this on my machine and it worked perfectly. But since boot2docker seems to work for you now, you obviously don't need an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It has been repaired with 1.7.1

see: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/979#issuecomment-121574822

Comment: The OP is neither using VirtualBox 5 nor docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try and start boot2docker with a minimal PATH.

As I illustrated in "[How to get Docker to run on a Windows System behind a corporate firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309)", I use:

```
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\prgs\git\latest\bin;C:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;c:\prgs\Boot2DockerforWindows;C:\Users\43640119\prog\b2d\
```

That is

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\prgs\git\latest\bin;
C:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin;

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;
c:\prgs\Boot2DockerforWindows;C:\Users\43640119\prog\b2d\
```

With `C:\prgs\git\latest` being a symlink to `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\`: [Git-for-Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) includes the latest from Git, with a recent msys2-based bash.

And VirtualBox being 4.x, not the last 5.0, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31423150/6309) by [hzpz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3790806/hzpz)

Comment: I don't see how to use this on Mac

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I don't see "Mac" in your question, and the issue you reference is about Windows.